# Mean of columns of different dataframes in r

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, mean, lapply

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),val1=c(1,2,3,NA,NA,6))
df2 <- data.frame(id=c(3,4,7,6,8) , val1=c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

Now what want is to combine the values of val1 from df1 and df2 as mean values which would be the `df1$val1`. For example:

```
df1$val1 <- mean(df1$val1,df2$val2, na.rm=TRUE) & match(by=id)
```

`df1$val1` should be the following

```
val1
1
2
2((3+1)/2)
4(4+NA/2)
NA
6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We coudl try

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df1, df2))[, .(val1 = mean(val1, na.rm = TRUE)), id][id %in% df1$id]
```

---

Or another option is

```
setDT(df1)[df2, val1 := rowMeans(cbind(val1, i.val1), na.rm = TRUE), on = .(id)]
```

Or as @Frank mentioned in the comments

```
setDT(df1); setDT(df2)
df1[, v := df2[df1, on=.(id), mean(c(x.val1, i.val1),
          na.rm=TRUE), by=.EACHI]$V1]
```

Comment: Just curious - why are you using `rbindlist(list(...))` instead of `rbind`? To get `data.table`?

Comment: @PoGibas Sorry, forgot to reply.  It is also possible, but I thought to use it to return a `data.table` or else have to do `setDT` before the `rbind`

Answer (score 1):

My solution using tidy.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),val1=c(1,2,3,NA,NA,6))
df2 <- data.frame(id=c(3,4,7,6,8) , val1=c(1,2,3,4,5))

df1 %>% left_join(df2, by="id") %>% select(2:3) %>% 
  transmute(val1=rowMeans(., na.rm=T))
```